# Unable to fetch data from Firebase Firestore in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am trying to GET data from Firestore but I cannot see data coming. I am building a react-native app. I am using react-native-firebase.

I also tried [Transactions](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/firestore/transactions) method from react-native-firebase documentation. But nothing is working.

Here' my code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid)
          .get()
          .then((doc)=>{ 
                  console.log(doc)
                  console.log(doc.data().shoppinglist)   
          })
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Console logging .get() gives me a Promise.

I am getting the Promise like this:

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
_40: 0
_55: null
_65: 0
_72: null
```

But .then() doesn't executes as the two console.log() ain't logging anything.

Please help me out here. Quite new with Firebase.

Comment: maybe you don't have such collection?

Comment: ofcourse I do Sir. I'm able to write data on that collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some [digging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) in Firebase Documentation, I found out a solution.

> Collection references and document references are two distinct types of references and let you perform different operations. For example, you could use a collection reference for querying the documents in the collection, and  **you could use a document reference to read or write an individual document.**

Therefore, Replacing `firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid)` **with** `` firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${uid}`) `` solved my problem.

Comment: This worked!!! Can you share how you performed your digging, and whats the root cause?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps! @uditbansal

Comment: but what about when you want the whole collection? a list of objects, how you achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For dummies in firebase like me, if you want a custom document id, you have to specify it when writing data to firestore

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .doc('ABC')
  .set({
    name: 'Ada Lovelace',
    age: 30,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User added!');
  });
```

Then you can get it by

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const user = await firestore().collection('Users').doc('ABC').get();
```

For reference: https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#writing-data